# Installing master branch of RefineryCMS gem from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I want to install the master branch of [refinerycms](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms)

I downloaded and extracted the tarball and then, after intialising a git repo, I ran `gem build refinerycms.gemspec`:

```
Successfully built RubyGem
Name: refinerycms
Version: 2.1.0.dev
File: refinerycms-2.1.0.dev.gem
```

I then ran `gem install refinerycms-2.1.0.dev.gem`

```
Unable to resolve dependencies: 
  refinerycms requires refinerycms-authentication (= 2.1.0.dev), 
  refinerycms-core (= 2.1.0.dev), 
  refinerycms-dashboard (= 2.1.0.dev), 
  refinerycms-images (= 2.1.0.dev), 
  refinerycms-pages (= 2.1.0.dev), 
  refinerycms-resources (= 2.1.0.dev)
```

So, this gem requires dev versions of other gems and I can't actually find some of them online (refinerycms-core for instance).

I can get the gem to install by running `bundle install` followed by `bundle exec gem install refinerycms-2.1.0.dev.gem` but this only installs the **refinerycms gem** and not the dependencies. In this case, I see output like:

```
Using refinerycms-core (2.1.0.dev) from source at /home/stephen/Desktop/resolve-refinerycms-5061179
```

So we're getting the dependency gems from the local source, can I actually install them so that they are stand-alone gems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

got the answer on the mailing list:

```
rails new application_name -m http://refinerycms.com/t/edge
```